# Prevent images from loading with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I am writing a script that replaces web page images with webp format. I have control only over my javascript which I can place where ever I want. My question is how to stop completely image load with javascript?
I tried to do like this:

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (let img of images) {
  img.src = '';
}
```

But when I open the network tab, browsers still download images.

Comment: your javascript loads on document ready so the request for the image may have already happened, the only way to stop the image loading is to not have the src set in the first place - you could try reversing it so you lazy load the images - set the src as a data attribute and use js to load it when they come onto the page - then you can ignore webp images

Comment: @Pete so there is no way to stop image loading with just javascript?

Comment: depends on how long your dom takes to load and how many concurrent requests you have but usually with a good internet connection the images will start loading before the script fires